# how can i add answer counter and at the end of 10 questions to give me my result

Tags: javascript, html, css

i added rest of the code as you asked html and css as well
hope it helps. all i want is to have a score of how many correct answers player got and after 10 questions i want it to end and give score and option to start game again or go to main page

```js
const startButton = document.getElementById('start-btn')
const nextButton = document.getElementById('next-btn')
const questionContainerElement = document.getElementById('question-container')
const questionElement = document.getElementById('question')
const answerButtonElements = document.getElementById('answer-buttons')



let shuffledQuestions, currentQuestionIndex

startButton.addEventListener('click', startGame)
nextButton.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    currentQuestionIndex++
    setNextQuestion()
})

function startGame(){
    startButton.classList.add('hide')
    shuffledQuestions = questions.sort(() => Math.random() - .5)
    currentQuestionIndex = 0
    questionContainerElement.classList.remove('hide')
    setNextQuestion()
}

function setNextQuestion(){
    resetState() 
    showQuestion(shuffledQuestions[currentQuestionIndex])
}

function showQuestion(question){
    questionElement.innerText = question.question
    question.answers.forEach(answers =>{
        const buttons = document.createElement('button')
        buttons.innerText = answers.text
        buttons.classList.add('btn')
        if(answers.correct){
            buttons.dataset.correct = answers.correct
        }
        buttons.addEventListener('click', selectAnswer)
        answerButtonElements.appendChild(buttons)
    });
}

function resetState(){
    clearStatusClass(document.body)
    nextButton.classList.add('hide')
    while(answerButtonElements.firstChild){
        answerButtonElements.removeChild
        (answerButtonElements.firstChild)
    }
}

function selectAnswer(e){
    const selectedButton = e.target
    const correct = selectedButton.dataset.correct
    setStatusClass(document.body, correct )
    Array.from(answerButtonElements.children).forEach(buttons=>{
        setStatusClass(buttons, buttons.dataset.correct)
    })
    if (shuffledQuestions.length > currentQuestionIndex + 1)
    {
        nextButton.classList.remove('hide')
    }else{
        startButton.innerText = 'restart'
        startButton.classList.remove('hide')
    }
    
}

function setStatusClass(element,correct){
    clearStatusClass(element)
    if(correct){
        element.classList.add('correct')
    }
    else{
        element.classList.add('wrong')
    }
}

function clearStatusClass(element){
    element.classList.remove('correct')
    element.classList.remove('wrong')
}

const questions = [
    {
        question: 'რისტი იყო მეფე ლუკა?',
        answers: [
            {text:'გერმანისტი', correct:true},
            {text:'რასისტი', correct:false},
            {text:'ტოიოტა ისტი', correct:false},
            {text:'ნაციონალისტი', correct:false}
        ]
    },
    {
        question: 'ვისი მენტორი და მასწევლებელი იყო მეფე ლუკა?',
        answers: [
            {text:'აკაკი წერეთლის', correct:false},
            {text:'ხვიჩა კვარაცხელიას', correct:false},
            {text:'ცუკენბერგის', correct:true},
            {text:'ჰიტლერის', correct:false}
        ]
    },
    {
        question: 'რომელ წელს იყო მისი კორონაცია?',
        answers: [
            {text:'ძვ.წ √603729', correct:true},
            {text:'გუშინ', correct:false},
            {text:'მზიან ღამეს', correct:false},
            {text:'რავი ძმაო აბა, არ ვარ აქაური', correct:false}
        ]
    },
    {
        question: 'იგი ტახტზე ავიდა 6 თვის ასაკში და... ?',
        answers: [
            {text:'პირველი ღამე ჰქონდა', correct:false},
            {text:'ძუძუს დაეწაფა', correct:false},
            {text:'კინაღამ გადმოვარდა', correct:true},
            {text:'პასპორტი აჩვენა ბიძიას', correct:false}
        ]
    },
    {
        question: 'როგორი იყო მეფე ლუკა?',
        answers: [
            {text:'ტირანი ვითარცა ქურციკი', correct:false},
            {text:'დაუნდობელი როგორც კოღო', correct:false},
            {text:'ბრძენი ვითარცა ბუ', correct:false},
            {text:'ყველა პასუხი სწორია', correct:true}
        ]
    },
    {
        question: 'რამდენი ადამიანი დაიღუპა აკვნის რევოლუციის დროს?',
        answers: [
            {text:'ქვეყნის მეორედი', correct:false},
            {text:'ქვეყნის მესამედი', correct:false},
            {text:'1/2 ქვეყნის', correct:false},
            {text:'პირველი და მესამე', correct:true}
        ]
    },
    {
        question: 'ზუსტად რომელ წელს გააჭენავა პირველად დინოზავრის კვიცი?',
        answers: [
            {text:'მის დაბადებამდე 2 დღით ადრე', correct:false},
            {text:'ხუი ივო ზნაეტ', correct:true},
            {text:'არ გაუჭენავებია', correct:false},
            {text:'აფხაზი ვარ, მალხაზი ვარ', correct:false}
        ]
    },
    {
        question: 'ორსული სპილოს ჭამის შემდეგ რისი დაყოლება შეუძლია?',
        answers: [
            {text:'ნიკორას კალცონესი', correct:false},
            {text:'ახოტნიჩი ძეხვის', correct:false},
            {text:'მთაწმინდის პონჩიკის', correct:false},
            {text:'ბიკენტიას ქაბაბის თავისი საწეპელათი', correct:true}
        ]
    },
    {
        question: 'ვინ გამოიწვია ჭამის ჩელენჯში?',
        answers: [
            {text:'ფიუდიფაი', correct:false},
            {text:'თი მაჭავარიანი', correct:false},
            {text:'ჰემინგუეი', correct:false},
            {text:'გიორგი XII', correct:true}
        ]
    },
    {
        question: 'რომელი ტელევიზია აშუქებდა ჭამის ჩელენჯს?',
        answers: [
            {text:'თუქული ტელეარხი CNN', correct:true},
            {text:'ალ ჯაზირა', correct:false},
            {text:'ალ ქაიდა', correct:false},
            {text:'ახოტა ი რიბალკა', correct:false}
        ]
    },
    

]
```

```css
*,*::before, *::after{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}

:root{
    --hue-neutral:200;
    --hue-wrong:0;
    --hue-correct:145;
}

body{
    --hue:var(--hue-neutral);
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color:hsl(var(--hue), 100%,20%) ;
}

body.correct{
    --hue:var(--hue-correct);
}
body.wrong{
    --hue:var(--hue-wrong);    
}

.container{
    width: 800px;
    max-width: 80%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px;
}

.btn-grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns:repeat(2,auto) ;
    gap: 10px;
    margin: 20px 0;

}

.btn{
    --hue:var(--hue-neutral);
    border: 1px solid hsl(var(--hue), 100%, 30%);
    background-color: hsl(var(--hue), 100%, 50%);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
}

.btn:hover{
    border-color: black;
}
.btn.correct{
    --hue:var(--hue-correct);
    color: black;
    
}
.btn.wrong{
    --hue:var(--hue-wrong);
    color: black;
    
}
.start-btn, .next-btn{
    font-size:1.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.controls{
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items: center;
}

.hide{
    display: none;
}
.home{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    --hue:var(--hue-neutral);
    border: 1px solid hsl(var(--hue), 100%, 30%);
    background-color: hsl(var(--hue), 100%, 50%);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="quizz.css">
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="scores" class="score">
            <div class="playerSection">
                <p id="playerScore">Player: 0</p>
            </div>
    
        <div id="question-container" class="hide">
            <div id="question">Question</div>
            <div id="answer-buttons" class="btn-grid">
                <button class="btn">answer1</button> 
                <button class="btn">answer2</button>
                <button class="btn">answer3</button>
                <button class="btn">answer4</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
            <button id="start-btn" class="start-btn btn">start</button>
            <button id="next-btn" class="next-btn btn hide">next</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="home">
        <a href="index.html"><button class="home">მთავარი</button></a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is js
dont know where and what to add
i tried watching some tutorials but couldnot do it
if u know easy solution pleas help
thank you

```
const startButton = document.getElementById('start-btn')
const nextButton = document.getElementById('next-btn')
const questionContainerElement = document.getElementById('question-container')
const questionElement = document.getElementById('question')
const answerButtonElements = document.getElementById('answer-buttons')



let shuffledQuestions, currentQuestionIndex

startButton.addEventListener('click', startGame)
nextButton.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    currentQuestionIndex++
    setNextQuestion()
})

function startGame(){
    startButton.classList.add('hide')
    shuffledQuestions = questions.sort(() => Math.random() - .5)
    currentQuestionIndex = 0
    questionContainerElement.classList.remove('hide')
    setNextQuestion()
}

function setNextQuestion(){
    resetState()
    showQuestion(shuffledQuestions[currentQuestionIndex])
}

function showQuestion(question){
    questionElement.innerText = question.question
    question.answers.forEach(answers =>{
        const buttons = document.createElement('button')
        buttons.innerText = answers.text
        buttons.classList.add('btn')
        if(answers.correct){
            buttons.dataset.correct = answers.correct
        }
        buttons.addEventListener('click', selectAnswer)
        answerButtonElements.appendChild(buttons)
    });
}

function resetState(){
    clearStatusClass(document.body)
    nextButton.classList.add('hide')
    while(answerButtonElements.firstChild){
        answerButtonElements.removeChild
        (answerButtonElements.firstChild)
    }
}

function selectAnswer(e){
    const selectedButton = e.target
    const correct = selectedButton.dataset.correct
    setStatusClass(document.body, correct )
    Array.from(answerButtonElements.children).forEach(buttons=>{
        setStatusClass(buttons, buttons.dataset.correct)
    })
    if (shuffledQuestions.length > currentQuestionIndex + 1)
    {
        nextButton.classList.remove('hide')
    }else{
        startButton.innerText = 'restart'
        startButton.classList.remove('hide')
    }
    
}

function setStatusClass(element,correct){
    clearStatusClass(element)
    if(correct){
        element.classList.add('correct')
    }
    else{
        element.classList.add('wrong')
    }
}

function clearStatusClass(element){
    element.classList.remove('correct')
    element.classList.remove('wrong')
}

const questions = [
    {
        question: 'რისტი იყო მეფე ლუკა?',
        answers: [
            {text:'გერმანისტი', correct:true},
            {text:'რასისტი', correct:false},
            {text:'ტოიოტა ისტი', correct:false},
            {text:'ნაციონალისტი', correct:false}
        ]
    },
    {
        question: 'ვისი მენტორი და მასწევლებელი იყო მეფე ლუკა?',
        answers: [
            {text:'აკაკი წერეთლის', correct:false},
            {text:'ხვიჩა კვარაცხელიას', correct:false},
            {text:'ცუკენბერგის', correct:true},
            {text:'ჰიტლერის', correct:false}
        ]
    },
    {
        question: 'რომელ წელს იყო მისი კორონაცია?',
        answers: [
            {text:'ძვ.წ √603729', correct:true},
            {text:'გუშინ', correct:false},
            {text:'მზიან ღამეს', correct:false},
            {text:'რავი ძმაო აბა, არ ვარ აქაური', correct:false}
        ]
    },
    {
        question: 'იგი ტახტზე ავიდა 6 თვის ასაკში და... ?',
        answers: [
            {text:'პირველი ღამე ჰქონდა', correct:false},
            {text:'ძუძუს დაეწაფა', correct:false},
            {text:'კინაღამ გადმოვარდა', correct:true},
            {text:'პასპორტი აჩვენა ბიძიას', correct:false}
        ]
    },
    {
        question: 'როგორი იყო მეფე ლუკა?',
        answers: [
            {text:'ტირანი ვითარცა ქურციკი', correct:false},
            {text:'დაუნდობელი როგორც კოღო', correct:false},
            {text:'ბრძენი ვითარცა ბუ', correct:false},
            {text:'ყველა პასუხი სწორია', correct:true}
        ]
    },
    {
        question: 'რამდენი ადამიანი დაიღუპა აკვნის რევოლუციის დროს?',
        answers: [
            {text:'ქვეყნის მეორედი', correct:false},
            {text:'ქვეყნის მესამედი', correct:false},
            {text:'1/2 ქვეყნის', correct:false},
            {text:'პირველი და მესამე', correct:true}
        ]
    },
    {
        question: 'ზუსტად რომელ წელს გააჭენავა პირველად დინოზავრის კვიცი?',
        answers: [
            {text:'მის დაბადებამდე 2 დღით ადრე', correct:false},
            {text:'ხუი ივო ზნაეტ', correct:true},
            {text:'არ გაუჭენავებია', correct:false},
            {text:'აფხაზი ვარ, მალხაზი ვარ', correct:false}
        ]
    },
    {
        question: 'ორსული სპილოს ჭამის შემდეგ რისი დაყოლება შეუძლია?',
        answers: [
            {text:'ნიკორას კალცონესი', correct:false},
            {text:'ახოტნიჩი ძეხვის', correct:false},
            {text:'მთაწმინდის პონჩიკის', correct:false},
            {text:'ბიკენტიას ქაბაბის თავისი საწეპელათი', correct:true}
        ]
    },
    {
        question: 'ვინ გამოიწვია ჭამის ჩელენჯში?',
        answers: [
            {text:'ფიუდიფაი', correct:false},
            {text:'თი მაჭავარიანი', correct:false},
            {text:'ჰემინგუეი', correct:false},
            {text:'გიორგი XII', correct:true}
        ]
    },
    {
        question: 'რომელი ტელევიზია აშუქებდა ჭამის ჩელენჯს?',
        answers: [
            {text:'თუქული ტელეარხი CNN', correct:true},
            {text:'ალ ჯაზირა', correct:false},
            {text:'ალ ქაიდა', correct:false},
            {text:'ახოტა ი რიბალკა', correct:false}
        ]
    },
    

]
```

Comment: First of all please don't try to get around the question restrictions by copying the text multiple times (if there are any there is a reason), second could you explain your problem better?

Comment: i want to add correct answers counter for example 5/10 correct. and after 10 questions to end the quiz

Comment: Please add html too, with `[<>]` fiddle